# Set selected ion-tab-button border-bottom color

Tags: css, ionic-framework, tabs, ionic4

I am trying to set a border-bottom for the selected tab button in ionic-4. But seems like border property doesn't work in this case.

I tried using the box-shadow property as seen below, but it helps only with either border-top or border for the entire box. I am exactly looking for an option to set a border bottom color for my selected tab. I have tried the below 2 ways already, but didn't work.

```
ion-tab-button[aria-selected=true] {
   box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px blue inset;
}

ion-tab-button[aria-selected=true] {
   border-bottom: #212a49 2px;
}
```

Comment: try  border="0px 0px 5px 0px" !important;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting it like border:0 0 2px 0, I used border-bottom: solid #212a49 and it worked. Adding just the color directly without mentioning solid, dashed or dotted isn't working. So this was the way I achieved my desired view.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that might help:

## Where you put it

Because Ionic 4 uses web components, the files are compartmentalised. So the rule might not be being applied unless you put it in the scss file that's associated with it. Even then some styles cannot be modified.

## Use the shorthand method

There is a github issue somewhere that explains that, rather than adding tons of properties, they chose to expose the shorthand property which lets you set all of them.

If the border is going to work you would need to use shorthand version of the `border`, and set all 4 sides, rather than using `border-bottom` directly.